# Clear/clean out the view of current Terminal .jar?

Tags: java, terminal

I am aware of the `clear` command in a Terminal that will clear off the screen and return you to just (in my case): `harrisbookpro: ~harris$` and I just wanted to see if it was possible to do the same in my program (which runs through the terminal).

Comment: I think this task might be platform specific and that Java does not provide explicit support for it. If you look at the Console class, you'll notice that it doesn't support a clear() operation.

Comment: You should never presume to own the terminal. If you need a GUI develop a GUI, otherwise don't go messing with your user's terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using a terminal that undersands ansi-esc codes (like for example any linux terminal that uses the xterm protocol) you can use

System.out.println("\033[2J\n");

to clear the screen

Comment: thanks a lot! it turned out to only work when i compile the .java files.

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println("\033[2J");` works on Linux.